# Why is this scenario working with function overloading but not with generics?

Tags: typescript

Having these types

```
interface StringType {
  isString: true;
  value: string;
}

interface NumberType {
  isString: false;
  value: number;
}
```

this function overloading is working without errors

```
function overloadFunc(val: StringType): string;
function overloadFunc(val: NumberType): number;
function overloadFunc(val: StringType | NumberType): string | number {
  if (val.isString) {
    return 'w/e';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

, but with generics

```
function genericsFunc<T extends StringType | NumberType>(val: T): T extends StringType ? string : number {
  if (val.isString) {
    return 'w/e';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I get an error stating

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends StringType ? string : number'.

Am I doing something wrong in the Generics implementation?

Have I misunderstood something?

TS version: 4.7.2

[TS playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5gFQJ4AOKA3gFDLLADO6mIWAXMhgK4QDc5yAbnADZsmVDNk4BfUqVCRYiFADkWAWwBG0fEWRkK1Wtibw+VDl14CITEMrVRxkmCxAIwwAPYhkr7tD6u4AEwAxRwQACjMmPXoNCABKIRF6TgcnF3dPbyhfAOCncP4mRVV1QjjLa2hkkLSPLx8-IJD8vkjE3FLkAB9kIpsY+ORhOiwu5CtiqC0uYBhkZoA6XTbYqYoKKAgwFigPAHIAdwB6CF3OCgkuDa2d5AAGO1IU5zcPLAgQaGAEKlyEAB4cMgIAAPSAgfxUNBtGKjXolIgAPmaTBwA0BILBEKhwxhAH5Bm1kOUJqtKLMFkthittGsrts9kcTmdkBd1pt6XdxEA)